# How to reset the position of object to their start position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

at some point, I want to reset all objects with the `PhysicsObject` script attached to their first position.

```
public class PhysicsObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitOnPickup = 0.1f;
    public float breakForce = 35f;
    [HideInInspector] public bool pickedUp = false;
    [HideInInspector] public Interactions playerInteractions;
    Vector3 originalPosition;
    Quaternion originalRotation;
    public Rigidbody rigidbody; 
    private void Start()
    {
        originalPosition = transform.position;
        originalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (pickedUp)
        {
            //collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > breakForce
            if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > breakForce)
            {
                 playerInteractions.BreakConnection();
                
            }           
        }  
    }

    public void ResetObjects()
    {
       transform.position = originalPosition;
        transform.rotation = originalRotation;
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my other Script:

```
 PhysicsObjects Physics;  
 private void Start()
    {
        GameObject inter = GameObject.Find("SeatPillow");
        Physics = inter.GetComponent<PhysicsObjects>();
    }
.... 
Physics.ResetObjects();
```

I tested this only for one object which is `SeatPillow` and it worked as I specified this object here: `GameObject inter = GameObject.Find("SeatPillow");`, How would I make this work for all the objects with `PhyiscsObject` attached without having to specify each one of them?

Comment: Do not name the method `Reset`, since it is called when you use the "Reset" feature in the editor. Just call it something different, to prevent unwanted behavior.

Comment: ok I renamed it. it was working tho for the object I tested.

Comment: Of course, it was working. You can also call ´Update´ or ´Start´ from another location in your code. I just wanted to make you aware of unwanted behavior.

Comment: ok, thank you for the advice. Do you know how I can apply this to all objects with the PhysicsObject Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `List` of `PhysicsObjects` and populate it when Instantiating desired objects, then use `foreach` to operate on all of them - `physicsObjectsList.ForEach(x => x.Reset());`

note: if you are not instantiating those objects from scripts then create `public` (or `[SerializeField] private`) list and drug and drop all desired objects from scene to that "other Script" component

Comment: what the type of the variable x?

Comment: `PhysicsObjects` i guess?!
List should be populated with objects attached `PhysicsObjects` component

Comment: Yes, I tried this. the code is inside one of the objects that have the PhysicsObject attached, and when I test it only this particular object is being reset to its original position. even though, I removed this line: GameObject inter = GameObject.Find("SeatPillow"); I don't know why it is still happening.

Comment: I mean the object that has the loop is the only one that gets resetted. I attached all objects to the list in the inspector.

Comment: If I correctly understood you wrote a loop in the `PhysicsObjects`, that's the wrong approach, you need another script to do so, create a new Controller, for example, `ResetPositionController`, attach to the GameObject that never gets destroyed and exists in scene whole cycle and operate on all objects that has attached PhysicsObjects  component from that script (`ResetPositionController`)